# Create Order In Pine script strategy on % of equity

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

### My Strategy arguments:

```
strategy("Name ABC",
 shorttitle="ABC",
 overlay=true, 
 initial_capital=135,
 currency=currency.USD,
 default_qty_value=25,
 margin_long=0,
 default_qty_type= strategy.percent_of_equity,
 commission_value=0.075)
```

### And I am creating order on certain condition:

```
strategy.order("Buy", strategy.long, comment="Entry")
```

**And on certain condition I close all order.**

```
strategy.close("Buy", comment="Exit")
```

### What I want:

- Each order quantity should be derived from 25 % of available equity.

### What I am getting:

[image]

### What's in image:

- Multiple order
- And all order has been closed on `2021-07-16 21:15`
- Suppose 1st Order

  > Available Equity 135
  > 25% of equity is 135*25/100 = 33.75
  > Market Price On 1st order is 12.14
  > So Contracts = 33.75 / 12.14 = 2.78
  > So Contracts is 2 on 1st order
- On 2nd Order

  > Available Equity 135-33.75 = 101.25
  > 25% of equity is 101.25*25/100 = 25.3125
  > Market Price On 1st order is 11.99
  > So Contracts = 25.3125 / 11.99 = 2.11
  > So Contracts is 2 on 2nd order
- But On 3rd Order

  > Available Equity 101.25-25.3125 = 75.9375
  > 25% of equity is 75.9375*25/100 = 18.98
  > Market Price On 3rd order is 12.02
  > So Contracts = 18.98 / 12.02 = 1.57
  > So Contracts should be 1 on 3rd order

### My Question:

- How this can be possible to create multiple order if you have only **$135** and you are using 25% of equity on each order.
- Please guide me where I am wrong and what should be the right solution.
- And One last: In above image how exactly **tradingview** creating order.

Comment: Until you position will be closed, the equity is not reduced after each order placement. The `strategy.percent_of_equity` uses strategy.equity for calculations but not `buying power`(you called it `Available Equity`).

Comment: @AndreyD That means strategy.percent_of_equity not full filling real trading scenario ? Can you suggest anything for this.

Comment: I recommend to calculate order's contracts manually in your case.